# How can I change dropdown selection based of radio buttons selection?

Tags: shopify

I have shopify application where user can choose different variants of products.
I'd like to change the product dropdown based on the selection of radio button, my product page looks like this.
[image]

I'd like to change the dropdown value based of the radio button selection.

This my dropdown code:

```
 <select name="id" id="ProductSelect-{{ section_id }}" class="product-single__variants no-js">
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
      {% if variant.available %}
        <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
          selected="selected" {% endif %}
          value="{{ variant.id }}">
          {{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}
        </option>
      {% else %}
        <option disabled="disabled">
          {{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
        </option>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

And this is my radio buttons code

```
  <fieldset class="variant-input-wrap"
    name="{{ option.name }}"
    data-index="option{{ option_index }}"
    id="ProductSelect-{{ section_id }}-option-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
    {%- for value in option.values -%}
      {%- assign product_available = true -%}
      {%- if product.options.size == 1 -%}
        {%- assign product_available = product.variants[forloop.index0].available -%}
      {%- endif -%}
      <div
        class="variant-input"
        data-index="option{{ option_index }}"
        data-value="{{ value | escape }}">
        <input type="radio"
          {% if option.selected_value == value %} checked="checked"{% endif %}
          value="{{ value | escape }}"
          data-index="option{{ option_index }}"
          name="{{ option.name }}"
          class="variant__input-{{ section_id }}{% unless product_available %} disabled{% endunless %}{% if is_color %} variant__input--color-swatch-{{ section_id }}{% endif %}"
          {% if is_color %} data-color-name="{{ value | escape }}"{% endif %}
          {% if is_color %} data-color-index="{{ color_option_index }}"{% endif %}
          id="ProductSelect-{{ section_id }}-option-{{ option.name | handleize }}-{{ value | url_encode }}">
        {%- if is_color -%}
          {%- assign color_image = value | handle | append: '.' | append: swatch_file_extension | asset_img_url: '50x' | prepend: 'https:' | split: '?' | first -%}
          {%- assign color_swatch_fallback = value | split: ' ' | last | handle -%}
          <label
            for="ProductSelect-{{ section_id }}-option-{{ option.name | handleize }}-{{ value | url_encode }}"
            class="variant__button-label color-swatch color-swatch--{{ value | handle }}{% unless product_available %} disabled{% endunless %}"
            style="background-image: url({{ color_image }}); background-color: {{ color_swatch_fallback }};"
          >
            {{ value | escape }}
          </label>
        {%- else -%}
          <label
            for="ProductSelect-{{ section_id }}-option-{{ option.name | handleize }}-{{ value | url_encode }}"
            class="variant__button-label{% unless product_available %} disabled{% endunless %}">{{ value | escape }}</label>
        {%- endif -%}
      </div>
    {%- endfor -%}
  </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to go about this, most of which involve JavaScript. Below are two different approaches.

The ideal way to go about this would be to remove the `<select>` all together and use the [Shopify Ajax API](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api) to add the item to the cart. By using this method, you can get the selected variant from the `<radio>` directly instead of the `<select>`.

The hacky way to do this would be to set the select visibility to hidden and use JavaScript to set the `<select>` selected `<option>` when a `<radio>` value is changed.